# How to store series of list Element for future calculation?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a Genetic-algorithm problem. The problem is to find best top 5 path from start to Goal.

I convert my playground to 0, 1 and stored them into Numpy array.

I know that every GA problem should have a population. My population starts from start point which is [12,0] and add every single movement(up, down, right, left, ...) to it and measure it's fitness.

Now i don't know how to have series of playground element.

for example start point[12,0]+up[-1,0]=current[11,0], I want to have a data structure to store my movements. Something like([12,0],[11,0],...).

```
grid = np.array([
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
start = [12,0]
neighbors = [(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0),(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)]
pop=[]
for i in neighbors:
    new=start[0]+i[0]
    new1=start[1]+i[1]
    pop.append([new,new1])
print(pop)
```

Code works, but i want to access to detail of movements.

Comment: Why can't you just use a list and then just keep appending those value? (e.g. `movements = [[12,0],]` and then every time there is a new move `movements.append([11,0])`